# regex split on Boolean

Tags: regex, r

I wish to split a string into vectors and lists.  If there is a `OR` or an `||` I want to split into lists.  If there is AND`or`&&`split into a vector.  With the word version I get it but not with the use of`|`and`&`.  Here is the code:

```
splitting <- function(x) {
    lapply(strsplit(x, "OR|[\\|\\|]"), function(y){
       strsplit(y, "AND|[\\&\\&]")
    })
}

splitting("3AND4AND5OR4OR6AND7") ## desired outcome for all three
splitting("3&&4&&5||4||6&&7")
splitting("3&&4&&5OR4||6&&7")
```

Here is the desired outcome:

```
> splitting("3AND4AND5OR4OR6AND7")
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "3" "4" "5"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "4"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "6" "7"
```

How can I set this regex appropriately?  What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: Please note R regex is specific to R.  If you do not have specific knowledge of R please do not respond.

Comment: Although R regexs tend to be a little different I think you're at a point where you should be able to adapt a solution from a non-R user.  Just make sure to double escape your backslashes and if it's sufficiently complex make sure to use perl=TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying it's the best answer but if you've already solved the problem using "AND" and "OR" then why not reduce it down to a problem you've already solved?

```
splitting <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("&&", "AND", x, fixed = TRUE)
  x <- gsub("||", "OR", x, fixed = TRUE)

  lapply(strsplit(x, "OR|[\\|\\|]"), function(y){
    strsplit(y, "AND|[\\&\\&]")
  })
}

splitting("3AND4AND5OR4OR6AND7") ## desired outcome for all three
splitting("3&&4&&5||4||6&&7")
splitting("3&&4&&5OR4||6&&7")
```

this was just the first thing that popped into my head and I haven't really thought about if there is a better way to do it.

Also this appears to work

```
splitting <- function(x) {
  #x <- gsub("&&", "AND", x, fixed = T)
  #x <- gsub("||", "OR", x, fixed = T)

  lapply(strsplit(x, "OR|\\|\\|"), function(y){
    strsplit(y, "AND|\\&\\&")
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks I was thinking I had to group the escaped characters with braces but that actually isn't sensible.  thanks. +1